# 500 internal server error when trying to access phpMyAdmin after installing VestaCP control panel

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have just installed LAMP and VestaCP and nothing else.

After checking the error log among those line I saw also:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
  name, using 1st.example.com.
  Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress thi$

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
  name, using 127.0.1.1.
  Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mess$
```

Here is also the full paste bin error log file https://pastebin.com/dhAHiGb7

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70599/discussion-on-question-by-mark178-500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-acces).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally there is no single guide on installing LAMP -that I know of-; however as you have not edited the .htaccess file manually, my educated guess would be, that in the main configuration file (or in the Virtual Host config file the directive `AllowOverride AuthConfig` is missing.

The tricky part is to find the right file. For VestaCP (https://vestacp.com/docs/#config-log-location-debian-ubuntu) you have the following default configs:

- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- /etc/apache2/conf.d/*
- /home/$user/conf/web/apache2.conf
- /home/$user/conf/web/sapache2.conf

You have to locate the config containing the directives for PHPMyAdmin.

Try something like

```
grep -r phpmyadmin /etc/apache2/*
```

In the corresponding file you should find

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
...
</Directory>
```

If so, you could add

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

within the `<Directory ..> </Directory>` Section and restart the apache2 service.

Comment: grep -r phpmyadmin /etc/apache2/* does not open anything

Comment: This is not looking good; as you run your LAMP Server as a Droplet, I am not sure about the internal configuration of the apache webserver. Have you tried to pose your question on the VestaCP Forum (https://forum.vestacp.com/)? Otherwise you would have to "reverse engineer your apache config by follwoing the apache process. I could try to guide you through the apache runtime configuration - but this will take some time an effort (and not tonight!).

Comment: When installing phpMyAdmin in a secure way(a guide I found online), I created a .htaccess file in order to secure phpMyadmin  -----  it was something like this   ------   AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Restricted Files"
       AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
       Require valid-user

Comment: How can I contact another time?

Comment: I will try to find some time tomorrow and post another anwser detailing the first steps; and you can follow up in comments.

Answer (score 0):

How to find the current apache webserver config:

1. Find the main httpd process `ps axuww | grep 'root.*http[d]'` which should yield something like

> root   1480   0.0  0.0  90788  7756  -  SsJ  20:25    0:00.03 /usr/local/sbin/httpd

Lookout for the command, note if any config file is stated e.g. `/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

2. If no startup configfile is referenced with `-f` , we have to find the default config directory:

> ```
> /usr/sbin/httpd -V
> Server version: Apache/2.4.25
> ...
>  -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local"
>  -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="etc/apache24/httpd.conf"
> ```

We are looking for the compiletime variables HTTPD_ROOT and SERVER_CONFIG_FILE. If the latter is not an absolute filepath, as above, it is expanded by the HTTPD_ROOT dir path; if SERVER_CONFIG_FILE is empty it defaults to `$HTTPD_ROOT/conf/httpd.conf`.

3. Parsing the main configfile

We should have located the runtime configfile and are now parsing for the relevant directives. Among these are

- ServerRoot
- Include or IncludeOptional
- DocumentRoot
- Alias / ScriptAlias
- and all  and  Containers

Firstly we have to locate the directory container for phpmyadmin. Therefore parse all configfiles that are referenced by the Include directives for 'php'. In the good old days you had a Alias/ScriptAlias directive and a corresponding  or  Container for PHP together with a `SetHandler` directive. Nowadays you could have a php-fpm daemon running on your system which is connected through proxy_fcgi.

Comment: Stefan, I found an answer in the morning in VetstaCP forum. Since VestaCP by default would install apache server and some other features(by doing so VestaCP rewrites previews configuration). I wanted VestaCP to create a database, now I did create a database with a few lines of codes. I would like to keep a contact with you if I would have any questions as I am still in the process of completing this VPS. How can we remain in touch? Thanks so much so far.

Comment: No problem; I am not aware, that you can contact individual users directly, but just tag your question here on AskUbuntu with VestaCP and I should receive a notification.

Comment: Hey Stefan, hope you are doing well. I have a problem but haven't found a solution yet. This is the url question that I have asked https://askubuntu.com/questions/992645/err-too-many-redirects-when-trying-to-redirect-non-www-to-www